# Unable to execute Sql query in node.js using mysql module

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Below is my app.js file content. When i try to execute this in node i am getting  "*Error while performing Query.*" Although this table contains 5 rows but still something seems to be wrong. Please let me know where i am doing wrong

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "mydata"
});

con.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
  con.query("select * from club_data ", function(err, rows,field) {
  if (!err)
  {
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
   }
  else
    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  });
});



con.end(function(err) {
  // The connection is terminated gracefully
  // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
  // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
});

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
```

**Server Output:**

```
PS C:\Users\skull_king\Desktop\Workspace> node .\app.js
Connection established
Error while performing Query.
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `err`? What is the exact error message?

Comment: console.log('Error while performing Query.'); this gets printed

Comment: PS C:\Users\skull_king\Desktop\Workspace> node .\app.js
Connection established
 Error while performing Query. 
 `{ [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT',
 fatal: false }`

Comment: What happens if you remove `con.end()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Node.JS is mostly *asynchronous*. The request handler that you declare with `app.get(...)` is not executed immediately, but only later, when the first (or any) request is received.

Immediately after declaring the request handler, you're *closing* the MySQL connection with the `con.end(...)` call even before the first request is handled. When you're trying to handle the request, `con` is already closed, because you have closed it with `con.end` before.

What you are probably trying to achieve is to close the MySQL connection when the server shuts down. For that, you could listen on the server's `close` event (untested, though):

```
app.on('close', function() {
    con.end();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine for me now.  Since it is asynchronous i put con.end before app.get(..) gets out of scope.

Comment: Happy to help. Not sure if closing the connection at the end of the handler is a good idea, though. Won't then the connection be closed after the first request?