# Connection issue while trying run my mysql query via nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have a query and I am trying to run the query. The issue i think is that i have added a condition where an item from a column from the database must equal to the computer name of the user.

Hence, I created a variable called `computerName` that simply retrieves the host name of the computer via NodeJs.

```
var os = require("os");
var computerName = os.hostname(); // Detect the computer name associated with the tablet
```

Below is the query

```
 connection.query("SELECT box_id, longestDimension from box where longestDimension != '' AND LOWER(box_id) = LOWER(computerName)", function(err, rows, fields) {
```

`computerName` seems to be the problem because when the query is run with a generic name such as box45 it works.

I am getting connection error. I guess the better question is how do I include a defined variable into the query

Comment: Why would you get a connection error if your query executes? Post the exact error

Comment: The precise error i get is Error while performing Query.

Comment: Could you post the whole file or the relevant part of the mysql connection handling. There are several possible problems. Mostly caused by the asynchronous behaviour of node. So when do you close you connection? When does the process ends. Maybe the query is not finished when the process ends?

Comment: Maybe the same root cause like here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962069/unable-to-execute-sql-query-in-node-js-using-mysql-module

Comment: Thanks i know its not a nodejs issue because i previously ran the query without the variable name computerName and if i replace it with something like box45 it works, it just breaks when i leave the computerName. Someone mention string concatanation as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to insert `computerName` directly into your SQL statement. At minimum, you'd need to write something like

```
connection.query("SELECT box_id, longestDimension from box where longestDimension != '' AND LOWER(box_id) = LOWER('" + computerName + "')", function(err, rows, fields) {
```

But you should be escaping the value of `computerName`. You don't know what value it might contain.

```
connection.query("SELECT box_id, longestDimension from box where longestDimension != '' AND LOWER(box_id) = LOWER('" + connection.escape(computerName) + "')", function(err, rows, fields) {
```

But a better way to do it is with ? substitution:

```
connection.query("SELECT box_id, longestDimension from box where longestDimension != '' AND LOWER(box_id) = LOWER(?)", computerName, function(err, rows, fields) {
```

Also, if the collation of the box_id column is case insensitive, which is usually the default, then you can skip the lowercasing the values.

I'd write it like this, for readability

```
let sql = "SELECT box_id, longestDimension FROM box WHERE longestDimension != '' AND box_id = ?";
connection.query(sql, computerName, function(err, rows, fields) {
```

Or if your node version supports template literals

```
let sql = `SELECT box_id, longestDimension
           FROM box
           WHERE longestDimension != ''
           AND box_id = ?`;
connection.query(sql, computerName, function(err, rows, fields) {
```

If you have multiple variables there's two ways to do it: with an object, or with an array.

Object method:

```
let payload = {
  box_id: "Johannesburg",
  longestDimension: 12.4
};
let sql = 'INSERT INTO box SET ?';

connection.query(sql, payload, function(err, rows, fields) {
});
```

Array method:

```
let computerName = "Johannesburg";
let longestDimension = 12.4;
let sql = 'INSERT INTO box SET box_id = ?, longestDimension = ?';

// alternative, equivalent SQL statement:
// let sql = 'INSERT INTO box (box_id, longestDimension) VALUES (?, ?)';

connection.query(sql, [ computerName, longestDimension ], function(err, rows, fields) {
});
```

You can even combine them

```
let payload = {
  box_id: "Johannesburg",
  longestDimension: 12.4
};
let boxName = "Box A";
let sql = 'UPDATE box SET ? WHERE box_name = ?';

connection.query(sql, [ payload, boxName ], function(err, rows, fields) {
});
```

In this last example, the payload object is substituted for the first `?` and the boxName variable is substituted for the second `?`.

Comment: Thank you for all of that. It works. I believe I am using the latest version of node, but it doesnt seem to be support litterals,its actually in strict mode. More precisely, this is the error i get SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: @John do you have `"use strict";` at the top of your file?

Comment: Note, that those are backticks for the template literal, not the normal single quote character. The error about "let, const, ..." sounds like you're not running in strict mode. In that case, avoid the template literal and substitute `var` for `let`.

Comment: no i dont have use strict on top. What would be the benefit?

Comment: Strict mode helps you avoid programming errors. Without it, amonst other things, javascript will silently accept certain errors like undeclared variables. [MDN Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: is it thus recommended to use strict on every js page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128654/discussion-between-dave-and-john).

Comment: BTW how would substitiution works with mutliple variables?

Comment: @John I've added some examples with multiple variables.

Comment: Thank you dave. Really useful!

Comment: My last minor edit if you dont mind is how would insert work, like if i was trying to insert these values into the database instead?

Comment: The latest three example are two INSERT statements and one UPDATE statement.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.